# Import Instagram post as Wordpress post

Tags: php, import, xml, bulk-import

I've been searching a lot but haven't found one very simple thing: how to import a post created on Instagram and turn it into a Wordpress post, that is, copy one Instagram post (text + photo) and create a simple post on the Wordpress blog?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the **Instagram feed** plugin
2. Set up the plugin, go to plugin list, then under instagram feed press settings and set it up.
3. To customize it, use customize bar
4. Go to display feed bar, and copy then [instagram feed] code
5. go on wordpress editor, press add block and search for shortcode
6. Paste the copied code

Above is for adding instagram feed. To add single instagram post after installing plugin, go to wordpress editor, press add block and search for instagram, and click on widget that shows up.

Enter the URL of post you want to share and press embed.

Comment: Thanks, but please, insert links for reference.

Comment: here you go https://youtu.be/av5OBKMQeqY

Comment: Could you be more specific? This video is outdated and currently, there are dozens of "Instagram Feed" plugins. Please, send the direct plugin link.

Comment: this is the only link I can currently get since its night time https://wpall.club/wp-plugins/instagram-feed-2/?utm_source=blogs&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=cross_promotion

Comment: This is not the same plugin. When you make an answer, be sure to have confirmed all the information before.

Comment: it is updated version, I just cant get the link on my phone to prove

Comment: This link redirects to Smash Balloon Social Photo Feed, and there it says clearly it "view" Instagram feeds, not import it to new Wordpress posts, as I've asked in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

U can use wpautomatic to import insta posts as a WP post. U can set up as many sources as you want. I have about 20 running. Importing insta posts based on users.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/250749)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using and configuring Zapier: https://zapier.com/

With Zapier you'd connect your Instagram and WP site, then set up a "zap" that listens for new Instagram posts, then when that happens it triggers another "zap" that pulls the information from the Instagram post and creates a WP post. IMO that would be the easiest way to achieve what you've described.

I currently have Zapier set up in the opposite way, everytime a blog post happens on a particular website, it creates an instagram, facebook, linkedin, and twitter post using the data from the WP post.